# Cannot invoke 'JSON' with an argument list of type '((Any))' - Using AlamoFire & SwiftyJSON

Tags: swift, alamofire, swifty-json

In my previous project using older versions of Alamofire and SwiftyJSON, using JSON(response.result.value) worked just fine. I've tried to implement code in my new project but getting some errors I haven't seen before. I did see some questions asked about it here on SO, but none of the solutions seemed to resolve my issue (unless there's something I missed).

```
AF.request(self.apiEndpoint,
             method: .get,
             parameters: self.parameters,
             headers: self.headers,
             interceptor: nil).validate().responseJSON { (response) in

                switch response.result {
                case .success(let value):
                  let json = JSON(value)
                  print(json)
                case .failure(_):
                  print(response)
                }
}
```

This returns the following error:

```
Cannot invoke 'JSON' with an argument list of type '((Any))'
```

Comment: `responseJSON` can be `Any`thing, you have to cast it to the expected type. A simple solution is to replace `responseJSON` with `responseData`

Comment: I get the same problem: Cannot invoke 'JSON' with an argument list of type '((Data))'

Comment: You can use the explicit initializer `JSON(data: ` but it should work also as suggested. Do you use the most recent version of SwiftyJSON?

Comment: Yes, I'm using the most recent versions available with cocoapods. When I add the label JSON(data: value), I get: Extraneous argument label 'data:' in call

Answer (score 0):

This is a strange situation. However, what I managed to identify was that if I call

```
JSON(value)
```

This fails with the error of not being able invoke the constructor with type (Any).

However, when I explicitly name the module as follows:

```
let json = SwiftyJSON.JSON(value)
```

Xcode no longer complains about that error.

Very strange indeed. I did go back and check that JSON() referred to SwiftyJSON when attempting to use it without specifically naming the module - just to verify there wasn't some sort of method naming clash with something else - and it did. So I'm not entirely sure why this works, but hopefully it helps someone else out. Or someone can give me a better answer if I've done something incorrectly.